# Highlighted text after touching (android app)

Tags: java, android, highlight

I'm trying to figure out how to make the **text highlighted after touching it and again unhighlighted after choosing another option of answer**.

The layout looks like this:

1) text...

2) text...

3) text...

Comment: Sounds like a job for some Radio Buttons. Or an array of TextViews with onClickListeners and a foreach loop

Comment: add your code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onclick option 1, that is text1. Set its color as dark black or as you want for highlight, At the same time set colors of other two textview as normal. Apply same for other onclick options.

```
text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { text1.setHighlightColor(Color.BLACK); text2.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); text3.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); } });
```

text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { text2.setHighlightColor(Color.BLACK); text1.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); text3.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); } }); 
text3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { text3.setHighlightColor(Color.BLACK); text1.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); text2.setHighlightColor(Color.GRAY); } });

Comment: Thanks a lot user7352183

Comment: Thanks a lot user7352183. Im veeeeeery new in java programming and have no clue yet what you exactly wrote in this code :) The app im trying to write is kind of a quiz about historical knowledge. Is the word 'Listener' needed in this code even though this app has nothing to do with listening? Thank you :)

Comment: Kevin, i haven't any code.I don't even know how to start it with it. At the moment im reading  book about java and watching tutorials